# Classic RDS from VPC EC2s

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-vpc

My old RDS instance is deployed in "Classic," not VPC.

I have a new VPC with some EC2 instances in it, but I can't connect from these VPC EC2 instances to the RDS instance.

Security Groups from VPC are not showing up in the RDS security group configuration, and allowing access by IP address does not work either.

How do I do this? Moving the RDS isntance into the VPC, right now, is not an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Security groups won't be visible, because VPC security groups have no meaning outide their VPC... and your Classic instance is (of course) outside the VPC.

Private VPC IP addresses of the instances won't work in the security config, either, since they also have no meaning outside the VPC.

The solution is that you have to open up access (in the RDS security group) for the *public* IP addresses that will be visible to RDS --

If the VPC machines are in a public subnet, you would use each machine's public IP address.  (If the VPC machines are in a public subnet and don't have public IPs, that's an incorrect configuration).

If the VPC machines are in a private subnet, you need the public IP address(es) associated with the VPC's NAT instance(s) to be open in the RDS security group, because those VPC machines will be using that source address to contact the Classic RDS, and the address of the NAT instance is what will be visible to RDS.

Comment: So, I'm trapped basically to elastic ip for reliability until I move my DB into a VPC. Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to assign an elastic ip, but you do have to have your VPC subnet's routing table include a NAT instance, and that NAT instance's public IP has to be granted access to the classic RDS security group (just confirmed this works)